# Vue 3 Inject with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using the new Vue 3 Composition API and have written a "store" for reactive data.

```
const state = reactive<State>({
  accessToken: undefined,
  user: undefined,
});

export default {
  state: readonly(state),
}
```

On App creation I provide the store to all components:

```
const app = createApp(App)
  .provide("store", store)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router);
```

And finally in a component / view I inject the store to make use of it.

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  inject: ["store"],
  components: {
    IonContent,
    IonHeader,
    IonPage,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
    IonButton,
  },
  computed: {
    email() {
      return this.store.state.user.email;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately **Typescript doesn't like** the way I use `this.store` in the **computed** property `email()`

And says

> Property 'store' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{},
> {}, {}, { email(): any; }, {}, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false,
> ComponentOptionsBase<{}, {}, {}, { email(): any; }, {},
> ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, string,
> {}>>'

I mean everything works fine when I remove the `lang="ts"` in the `<script/>` tag, but without the error is displayed.
Any suggestions on how to fix this or what it particularly means?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend to use the store as a global property without specifying the `inject` in any child component because provide/inject could have some [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity) caveats:

```
const app = createApp(App)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router);
app.config.globalProperties.store= store;

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties  {
       store:any // replace it with the right type
     }
   }
```

then use it directly :

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: {
  ...
  },
  computed: {
    email() {
      return this.store.state.user.email;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

For those who are dealing with the same issue with Vue 3 + TS, I found a solution without having to change the `app.config` or declare a new `module`:

1. App.ts setup

```
import { createApp, reactive } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const Store = reactive({
  myProperty: 'my value'
})

createApp(App)
  .provide('Store', Store)
  .mount('#app')
```

2. The component accessing the injected reactive object:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ Store.myProperty }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IStore } from '@/types'
import { defineComponent, inject } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponentName',
  setup() {
    return {
      Store: inject('Store') as IStore,
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.Store) // will show the `Store` in the console
  }
})
</script>
```

3. The type defition for the Store (`@/types.ts`):

```
export interface IStore {
  myProperty: string
}
```

Following these 3 steps I was able to read/write to `Store.myProperty` without problems using TypeScript

Comment: and how use watch? in setup